# how to get positions of all found occurences of a boost::regex pattern in a string?

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, boost

I can't find working code for that, managed only to coin up this snippet, it compiles but gives wrong output.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp> 
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  string input = "123 apples 456 oranges 789 bananas oranges bananas";
  boost::regex re = boost::regex("[a-z]+");
  boost::match_results<string::const_iterator> what;
  boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
  string::const_iterator s = input.begin();
  string::const_iterator e = input.end();
  while (boost::regex_search(s,e,what,re,flags)){
    cout << what.position() << ", ";
    string::difference_type l = what.length();
    string::difference_type p = what.position();
    s += p + l;
  }
}
```

output is: `4, 5, 5, 1, 1,`

but should be: `4, 15, 27, 35, 43,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right, but failing to account for the fact that `cout << what.position() << ", ";` will output the matching string's position *relative to the end of the last matching string*, ie `s`.

Since `s` knows exactly where it is in relation to `input`, this should work:

`cout << ((s - input.begin()) + what.position()) << ", ";`

Comment: I got:`test.cpp:13:16: error: 'std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator' has no member named 'position'`

Comment: @rsk82 My mistake, I read the wrong type and didn't have a copy of boost around to test compile. Fixed now.